# For $f\in C^{\infty}[0,1]$ such that $\max_{[0,1]}|f^{(n)}|\le M^n\cdot n!$ prove that $f$ can be extended to analytic function on $G\supset [0,1].$

Tags: complex-analysis

For $f\in C^{\infty}[0,1]$ such that  $\max_{[0,1]}|f^{(n)}|\le M^n\cdot n!$ prove that $f$ can be extended to an analytic function on domain $[0,1]\subset G$.

What I am quite not sure about is a claim I came by several times, according to which, if a function has a radius of convergence such that its Taylor series converges around a real point, then it converges for the disk of the same radius around that point, but I find that pretty new, thinking that I can't even tell whether the function can work with complex inputs. Can you generally help me understand the above strategy relevance, and the logic according to which the above is true?

Comment: By $f^n$ do you mean $n$th power of $f$ or $n$th derivative of $f$?

Comment: What does $G$ mean in this context ?

Comment: $G$ stands for a connected open subset of $\Bbb{C}$ containing $ [0,1]$. As for the $f^n$, it was a typo...

Comment: What are you given about $M$?

Comment: The convergence of a Taylor series for a $C^\infty$ function $f$ does not imply that the Taylor series converges to $f$. As an example, for smooth functions with compact but nonempty support the Taylor series is usually identically $0$ at boundary points of the support. What you are actually supposed to show (and it's not so easy if I recall correctly) is that the inequality you have implies that the Taylor series of $f$ not only converges but converges to $f$ (locally near every point).

Comment: Actually, a $C^\infty-$function in a closed interval extends analytically iff $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\|f^{(n)}\|^{1/n}}{n}<\infty.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly different line of reasoning:

- Set $r = 1/M$ and define $B(a, r) = \{ z \in \Bbb{C} : |z - a| < r \}$ as the open ball of radius $r$ at $a$. Now for each fixed $a \in [0, 1]$, define $\tilde{f_a} : B(a, r) \to \Bbb{C}$ by

  $$ \tilde{f_a} (z) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (z-a)^n. $$

  Since $|f^{(n)}(a)/n!| \leq r^{-n}$, it follows that this series converges absolutely on $B(a,r)$ and hence defines a holomorphic function on $B(a,r)$.
- Now we claim that $f \equiv \tilde{f_a}$ on the interval $(a-r,a+r)\cap [0,1]$ for each $a \in [0, 1]$. Once this claim is proved, then a simple application of identity theorem tells that $\tilde{f_a} \equiv \tilde{f_b}$ whenever $B(a,r)$ and $B(b,r)$ intersects, and hence we can patch them together without ambiguity to create a holomorphic function on $G := \cup_{a \in [0,1]} B(a,r)$ which extends $f$.
- Proving the claim amounts to establishing that the Taylor series of $f$ at $a$ converges to $f$ on the prescribed interval. By the Taylor's theorem, we can write

  $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n + \frac{f^{(N+1)}(\xi)}{(N+1)!}(x-a)^{N+1} $$

  for some $\xi = \xi(a,x,N)$ between $a$ and $x$. Consequently, for $x \in (a-r,a+r)\cap[0,1]$, the remainder term satisfies the bound

  $$ \left| \frac{f^{(N+1)}(\xi)}{(N+1)!}(x-a)^{N+1} \right| \leq \left( \frac{|x-a|}{r} \right)^{N+1} \xrightarrow[]{N\to\infty} 0. $$

  Therefore the Taylor series converges to $f$ on $(a-r,a+r)\cap[0,1]$ and the claim follows.

Comment: I had just started to write essentially this answer. My only complaint here is that you should have posted two minutes earlier, so I wouldn't have wasted time starting to type.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I feel sorry for that, especially thinking that I wasted a couple of minutes to check if this is a duplicate answer or not. :s

Answer (score 3):

Set
$$
g(x+iy)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x)(iy)^n}{n!}.
$$
Then, the series converges for all $z=x+iy$, with 
$$
|y|<\frac{1}{M}\quad\text{and}\quad x\in [0,1],\tag{1}
$$
and defines $C^\infty$ function for those $x,y$. In particular, $g$ coincides with $f$ in $[0,1]$ and 
$g$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations:
$$
g_y=ig_x.
$$
Thus $g$ is holomorphic in $(1)$.

A detailed proof, and generalisation, appears in:

G. Akrivis, D. T. Papageorgiou and Y.-S. Smyrlis, *On the analyticity of certain dissipative–dispersive systems*, Bull. London Math. Soc. 45 (2013) 52–60 [doi:10.1112/blms/bds061](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/45/1/52.full.pdf+html)

Comment: You can't really set $g$ equal to that series until you know it converges.

Comment: It is convergent. $$ |f^{(n)}(x)|\le n! M^n\,\,\,\text{and} \,\,\, |y|<r<\frac{1}{M}\Longrightarrow \frac{|f^{(n)}(x)(iy)^n|}{n!}<  (rM)^n\Longrightarrow\sum \frac{|f^{(n)}(x)(iy)^n|}{n!}<\frac{1}{1-rM}$$